# Compute the 100th power of a given matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So, I was asked this question in an interview. 
Given a matrix 
$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1& 1 \\ 1& 0& 1 \\ 1&1& 0\end{bmatrix},$$ 
find $M^{100}$.

How does one approach this question using pen and paper only?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Moo isn't P singular in this case?

Comment: @Skyuppercut: You are supposed to **upvote** the answers you found useful or beautiful and then **accept** one of them. See [the Tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common and neat trick.  If you diagonalize $M$ then you get $M=U^{-1} D U$, where $D$ is diagonal.  Now, consider $M^2$.  This equals $U^{-1} D U U^{-1} D U$.  But $ U U^{-1} = I$.  Therefore, $M^2= U^{-1} D^2 U$.  Hopefully you can see now (and it's easy to prove) that $M^N = U^{-1} D^N U$.  To compute $D^N$, just raise each diagonal element to the $N^{th}$ power.

Comment: You can do this even if the diagonalizing matrix $U$ is not orthogonal. Of course in that case you will have $M=U^{-1}DU$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro  Thanks; I adjusted the text.

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky enough after a couple of matrix multiplications you will discover
$$
\begin{cases}
M^n_{d}=\frac{2^{n}-2}{3},\quad M^n_o=\frac{2^{n}+1}{3};& n -\text{odd},\\
M^n_{d}=\frac{2^{n}+2}{3},\quad M^n_o=\frac{2^{n}-1}{3};& n -\text{even},\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $M^n_d$ and $M^n_o$ are diagonal and off-diagonal elements of the matrix $M^n$, respectively.

The observations leading to the result look like:
$$
M^{n+2}_d=2M^{n+1}_o=2(M^n_o+M^n_d)=2M^n_o+2M^n_d=M^{n+1}_d+2M^{n}_d,
$$
and similarly for $M_o$.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to avoid orthogonal diagonalization and square roots. The matrix of all ones has eigenvalues $(3,0,0),$ with eigenvectors (NOT normalized) as the columns of
$$
W =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Oh, we need the inverse,
$$
W^{-1} = \frac{1}{6}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 2 & 2 \\
-3 & 3 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Your matrix $M$ has the same eigenvectors with eigenvalues $(2,-1,-1).$ Therefore $M^{100}$ has the same eigenvectors with eigenvalues $(B,1,1),$ where $B = 2^{100}$ stands for BIG. We have the matrix equation for $M^{100} W,$ namely
$$
M^{100}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 2
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
B & -1 & -1 \\
B & 1 & -1 \\
B & 0 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
We multiply both sides **on the right** by $W^{-1},$ I got it wrong the first time,
$$
M^{100} = \frac{1}{6}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
B & -1 & -1 \\
B & 1 & -1 \\
B & 0 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 2 & 2 \\
-3 & 3 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 2
\end{array}
\right) =
 \frac{1}{6}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2B+4 & 2B-2 & 2B-2 \\
2B-2 & 2B+4 & 2B-2 \\
2B-2 & 2B-2 & 2B+4
\end{array}
\right) =
 \frac{1}{3}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
B+2 & B-1 & B-1 \\
B-1 & B+2 & B-1 \\
B-1 & B-1 & B+2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
This is all integers as $ B = 2^{100} = 4^{50}  \equiv 1^{50} \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

Comment: But the matrix is not ones(3)

Comment: @Skyuppercut But it has the same eigenvectors and almost the same eigenvalues (decremented by 1) as ones(3) matrix. However it hardly can be assumed that one can derive it during an interview.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another trick. Denote 
$$
\mathbf 1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1& 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}, $$ 
and let $I=\mathrm{diag}(1,1,1)$ be the identity matrix. Then by the binomial formula 
$$
M^{100}=(\mathbf 1 - I)^{100}=\sum_{k=0}^{100} \binom{100}{k}(-1)^k \mathbf 1^{100-k}, $$ 
so we are led to considering powers of $\mathbf 1$, which are easy to compute: 
$$\mathbf 1^{j}=\begin{cases} 3^{j-1}\mathbf 1, & j\ge 1 \\ I & j=0.\end{cases}$$ 
We conclude that $M^{100} = \big(\sum_{k=0}^{99} \binom{100}{k}(-1)^k 3^{100-k-1}\big)\mathbf 1 + I, $ and the binomial sum can be computed by observing that 
$$
(3-1)^{100}=\sum_{k=0}^{100} (-1)^k \binom{100}{k}3^{100-k}.$$ 
We conclude that 
$$
M^{100}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{2^{100}+2}3 & \frac{2^{100}-1}3 & \frac{2^{100}-1}3  \\ \frac{2^{100}-1}3 & \frac{2^{100}+2}3 & \frac{2^{100}-1}3  \\ \frac{2^{100}-1}3 & \frac{2^{100}-1}3 & \frac{2^{100}+2}3 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Please check. The diagonal term should be $(2^{100}+2)/3$ and off-diagonal - $(2^{100}-1)/3$.

Comment: @user355705: I checked with a computer algebra system. The result of my answer appears to be the correct one.

Comment: Firstly your matrix elements are not integer, which is already strange enough. Secondly the off and on-diagonal elements are equal.

Comment: Oh right, they must be integer, that's clearly an error on my part. The check I did was probably flawed because of the presence of large numbers

Comment: Ok, got it. I should consider the k=0 summand separately. This will produce the same formula as yours. Thank you for spotting the mistake!

Comment: @user355705 and Giuseppe, did it by, well, minimally clever linear algebra.

Comment: Meanwhile, note that ATM are in  second position, but Real Madrid are lagging in fourth

Comment: @WillJagy: I hope the Bears are doing well too :-)